# React Router - Placing components by iteration not working

Tags: reactjs, router

Given the following code:

```
const AdmNews = React.lazy(() => import('./components/adm/AdmNews'));
const AdmPeople = React.lazy(() => import('./components/adm/AdmPeople'));
    
const AdminRoutes = [
      {path:"/route/admin/news",component:<AdmNews/>},
      {path:"/route/admin/people",component:<AdmPeople/>},
    ]
```

---

```
 {AdminRoutes.map((el)=>{
        return <Route path={el.path} 
            element={
            <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}> 
            {el.component}
        </React.Suspense>
    }/> 
    })}
```

I'm trying to iterate over objects in order to create the routes in react, and when I click on the matching buttons, they understand the path property, and it *reacts* accordingly, however, the component is not loading. Is is right to have the component inside the object as show above: `component:<AdmNews/>`? (No errors are shown.)

PD. If I place the code manually without iteration, it works, so I suspect of `component:<AdmNews/>` not being the right approach.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it is the one to last line, after the closing bracket, @Rashomon

Comment: Did you wrap your routes with <Routes></Routes>

Comment: @Rahul, yes, everything is wrapped in <Router><Routes></Routes></Router>, I didn't paste the whole code to have a clean view of where I believe the problem is. As stated above, If I place the code manually with no iterator, it works.